# mailto link not working using Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, mailto

I am having trouble getting my `mailto` link working on this landing page. I have been googling and still have not found an answer why a simple `mailto` link is not working using Bootstrap.

I am trying to get the "Contact us" link in the top right menu to open a mail window and the "Refer now" link needs to go to an anchor tag lower in the page, code below. Webpage can be viewed at: [website code](http://iang.design/test/index.html)

```
<div class="col-xs-10 text-right menu-1 main-nav">
                <ul>
                    <li class="active"><a href="#benefits" data-nav-section="benefits">BENEFITS</a></li>
                    <li class="active"><a href="#requirements" data-nav-section="requirements">REQUIREMENTS</a></li>
                    <li class="active"><a href="mailto:surveyorhr@carf.org">CONTACT US</a></li>
                    <li><input type="submit" class='contact-button' value="REFER NOW" onclick="window.location.href='mailto:surveyorhr@carf.org'"></li>
                    <!-- For external page link -->
                    <!-- <li><a href="#" class="external">External</a></li> -->
                </ul>
            </div>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It seems strange to use an input type submit button for a mail link – those certainly are not made for mail links – apart from that any submit button would only work in the context of a form, i.e. inside a `form` element.

I would recommend to use a regular link and style it as a button using CSS.

(BTW: This has nothing to do with Bootstrap)

Answer (score 1):

Currently you have some js running in main.js that is manipulating click events and preventing default browser behavior. If you remove the class "main-nav" from the div that contains your mailto link it begins to function again. Based on that I would revaluate your use cases in that js file.